# AngularJs Delete operation not working

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Below is my code. Its an MVC project on asp.net. Can't find out what is the problem! Create, Update and Retrieve operations work successfully but don't know why delete operation is not working.

Code :

```
           $scope.delete=function(product)
           {
               var config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;' } };
               $http.delete('/Product/Delete',{params:{id:product.ProductId}},config).then(
                    function(response){
                        alert("Deleted");   
                        var index = $scope.Products.indexOf(product);
                        $scope.Products.splice(index, 1);     
                    }
                );
           };
```

Controller Code :

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public JsonResult Delete(int id)
    {
        Product oProduct = new Product();
        try
        {
            oProduct.ErrorMessage = oProduct.Delete(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oProduct = new Product();
            oProduct.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string sjson = serializer.Serialize(oProduct);
        return Json(sjson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Error Showing :
       DELETE http://localhost:1693/Product/Delete?id=16 404 (Not Found)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have api on same server? can you check exact path to work?

Comment: @Avnesh Shaky bro, There is no API, its a simple project that only do CRUD operation.  I check the path and for me its okay.

Comment: Ok.. so endpoints `'/Product/Delete'` is for what? Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You should call the URL like `/Product` without mentioning Delete in the URL, ASP.Net WebAPI will take care about calling Delete method, when you call `.delete` on `$http`

```
$http.delete('/Product',{params:{id:product.ProductId}},config)
```

Comment: @Ikr is it WebAPI `APIController` ?